# How to get currently compared value in if statement

Tags: python

```
if not sky.has_key('blue'):
    get_currently_compared_key # blue
elif not sky.has_key('cloud'):
    get_currently_compared_key # cloud
```

In above code, I want to get 'blue' in if statement. Is there any useful method?

Edited 1: if sky == 'blue' -> if not sky == 'blue'
Edited 2: if not sky.has_key('blue')...

Comment: There isn't any except replacing 'blue' with a variable/constant containing the string you want to compare sky against.
This way you can access the variable within the statement, or in general in your code

Comment: you want `if not sky == 'blue'`  or `if sky != 'blue'` ????

Comment: You should really ask the question you want from the start, not edit your question every time someone answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magic identifier that expands to `blue` inside the consequent, if that's what you mean, <del>although `sky` obviously has the value you're after</del>.

**Edit**: I suppose you mean `sky != 'blue'` instead of `not sky == 'blue'`. No, there's no magic way to get to the values under comparison in the condition. Either type `'blue'` again or create a variable holding it outside the conditional:

```
BLUE = 'blue'

if sky != BLUE:
    make_the_sky(BLUE)
```

**Edit 2**: okay, so it's `has_key`. Still no magic. Note that `has_key` has been deprecated for quite some time in favor of `'blue' in sky` (or `'blue' not in sky`).

Comment: Actually, I made mistake. if not sky... is what I mean.

Comment: @KenichiTakano: do you mean `sky != "blue"`? `not sky == "blue"` is always false since `not sky` evaluates to a boolean.

Comment: See edited code. This is exactly what I mean. Sorry for edit many times.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, the only way to do this is the obvious one:

```
sky_colour = 'blue'
if not sky == sky_colour:
    do_something(sky_colour)
```

Or for your edit:

```
sky_colour = 'blue'
if sky_colour not in sky:
    do_something(sky_colour)
```

`has_key()` is not needed - use the `in` keyword instead, it's more readable.

Comment: It seems I need obvious function. Thanks.